# How to set Firebase security read rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am creating a chat system and there is a search function where I can search users if user's profile is public. My firebase database structure is as follow.

```
users:{
     $uid1:{
          name:"John",
          created:13739373,
          type:"PRIVATE"
           },
     $uid2:{
          name:"Susan",
          created:12393930,
          type:"PUBLIC"
           },
     $uid3:{
          name:"Titan",
          created:12582938,
          type:"CLOSED"
           }
   }
```

So, I set `read` rule for **users** like this.

```
 ".read":"data.child('type').val()==='PUBLIC' || //if user is already friend, alse allow type CLOSED"
```

How to perfectly set `read` rule for **users** if type is `PUBLIC` or `CLOSED`(if two users are already friends). I can't set `read` rule under `$uid` because this is search function.

**Edit:** This is my `friends` path.

```
   friends:{
               $uid1:{
                          $uid2: 1273738,  //friend since timestamp
                          $uid3: 1274693,
                          $uid4: 1284869,
                         ...
                    }
           }
```

**Edit2:** `PUBLIC` is everyone can see, `PRIVATE` is no one can see/search and `CLOSED` is only friend can see.

Comment: Can I know the path for the friend data? Like where the details about the user and his/her friends are stored.

Comment: @Sushan Sapaliga I have updated my question. Now how should I query my search?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I will post the answer to your query.

Comment: You have 3 types of `type`: `PUBLIC`, `PRIVATE`, and `CLOSED`. `PUBLIC` everyone can see, `PRIVATE` means only friends can see and what about `CLOSED`?

Comment: I have posted the answer, waiting for your clarification about the `CLOSED` type.

Comment: `PUBLIC` is everyone can see, `PRIVATE` is no one can see/search and `CLOSED` is only friend can see. My class mate requested this feature in my school project.

Comment: I have made edits to my answer according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase realtime rules you have to update is,

```
"users": {
      "$user_id":{ 
        ".read": "data.child('type').val() == 'PUBLIC' || (data.child('type').val() == 'CLOSED' && auth != null && root.child('friends').child($user_id).child(auth.uid).val() > 0 ) || (data.child('type').val() == 'PRIVATE' && auth != null && $user_id == auth.uid ) "
}
```

Comment: I'm still waiting for `CLOSED` option, once you have mentioned its purpose, I will update my answer.

Comment: I have posted the whole branch rule so that you can understand whats the use of the `$user_id`. And also I have made changes to the rules if the type is `PRIVATE`, no one will be read it, except the owner user.

Comment: I changed as you suggested and tested in play ground. My path is `users/{uid}` and authenticaticated . But read rule get denied.

Comment: I even tried `".read":"data.child('type').val()== 'PUBLIC'` but it denied too. Why I get denied?

Comment: Can you upload the screen shot of your data so that I can recreate the error?

Comment: I can't read under `user` path. Your provided rule works fine when I read under a specific userID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220139/discussion-between-sushan-sapaliga-and-pak).